# Route multiple routes to same controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have one controller action that parses the request path to figure out the request URL to use from configatron. It's basically a large case statement, as the alternative was a bunch of methods all doing the same thing which doesn't seem very DRY.

Is there any Rails 4 way of routing multiple different routes to the same controller action without writing `to: 'controller#action'` for each route?

There was a `namespace :controller` option, but it uses the action of the route, i.e. `match 'users'` would result in `controller#users`.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing more detail about what you are trying to accomplish. Have you read the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)? Especially the section on route globbing.

Comment: Well that was exactly what I was looking for. Never crossed my mind to look at 'globbing'. Using that I just did `get '/data/*path', to: 'controller#get_data'` and then just checked `params[:path]` to determine the URL. Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to consider extracting the parsing to its own class to keep logic out of your controller.

Comment: I think for now it should be fine where it is. Its about a 10 line switch statement, so it's not taking up too much space that would make we want to abstract it away to a different class.